# Why are my clash of clans troops blurry?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When I deploy troops to attack or while it is trained already, it shows a blurred picture of the troops. Why?

[image]

Comment: It kind of looks glitched out to me.

Comment: It happens always isn't there a solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are my troops unclear?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288019/why-are-my-troops-unclear)

Comment: The dupe has no answer, so it won't help.

Comment: Try reinstalling the game?  I'm not sure how the game saves your progress, so before you do that, you may want to find out so you don't lose anything.

Comment: Found what might be the same issue here, but not much support. https://forum.supercell.com/showthread.php/630040-Troops-and-part-of-the-map-Blurred

Answer (score 1):

Well it also depends upon ram and memory as if you use a phone with bigger ran and memory it will work smoothly but complications may occur if you have a slow internet as it causes lag and causes game to crash or you may have virus of corruption's in your application. So try to use fresh copy of the game.

Answer (score 0):

This Depends on the device you are using.

For example, my old phone ran games at around 240p. Yep, 240.
My new phone, an I-phone7 runs games at around 720p. A whole lot better than 240.

If that isn't the problem, you need to delete the app, and files stored on your phone associated with it. Don't worry about your progress, it should save through you Cloud/Google Play.